# Show there exists infinitely many primes of the form $p_3 = p_0 + p_1 + p_2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

**Conjecture**

There exists infinitely many primes of the form $p_3 = p_0 + p_1 + p_2$.

**Proof**

Assuming these conjectures are true:

[Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) Every even number greater than $2$ is the sum of two primes.

$$p_0 + p_1 = 2k$$

[Maillet's conjecture](https://www.jstor.org/stable/90013051#:%7E:text=In%201905%2C%20Maillet%20conjectured%20in,forms%20of%20the%20con%2D%20jecture.) Every even number is the difference of two primes.

$$p_3 - p_2 = 2k$$

For $k > 2$, equating the two expressions

$$p_0 + p_1 = p_3 - p_2$$

and rearranging

$$p_3 = p_0 + p_1 + p_2$$

Since there are infinitely many $k$, there are infinitely many primes  of the form $p_3 = p_0 + p_1 + p_2$ $\blacksquare$

**Examples**

```
+-----+--------+----+-----+----+--------------------------+
|  k  |   2k   | p0 |  p1 | p2 |     p3 = p0 + p1 + p2    |
+-----+--------+----+-----+----+--------------------------+
|   5 |     10 |  3 |   7 |  3 |       13 = 3 + 7 + 3     |
|  50 |    100 |  3 |  97 |  7 |      107 = 3 + 97 + 7    |
| 250 |    500 | 13 | 487 | 23 |      523 = 13 + 487 + 23 |
+-----+--------+----+-----+----+--------------------------+
```

Comment: If Goldbach is true, then *every*  prime $>5$ is of this form.  Just apply Goldbach to $p-3$.

Comment: This is an obvious consequence of Vinogradov's theorem (a weak form of Goldbach's conjecture): every sufficiently large odd number is the sum of 3 primes (thanks to Helfgott, this is now known for all odd numbers $\ge 9$ or so).

Comment: Note too that [Vinogradov's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinogradov%27s_theorem#:~:text=In%20number%20theory%2C%20Vinogradov's%20theorem,odd%20integers%20greater%20than%20five.) actually establishes your result for every sufficiently large prime, no need for unproven conjectures.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can prove the same result on the strength of the Goldbach Conjecture alone. No need for Maillet's conjecture.

Let $p_0 \ge 7$ be any arbitrary prime number. Of course, any such number is odd, so $p_0 = 2k - 1$ for some positive integer $k \ge 4$. Now, minus the equation by $3$ to obtain

$$ p_0-3 = 2k-1-3 = 2k-4 = 2(k-2) $$

Hence, $p_0-3$ is twice some integer $k-2$, implying $p_0-3 \ge 4$ is even. Then, according to the Goldbach Conjecture, there exists two primes $p_1, p_2$ such that

$$ p_0-3 = p_1 + p_2 $$

and after adding $3$ to the equation, we have

$$ p_0 = p_1 + p_2 + 3 $$

Thus, if the Goldbach Conjecture is true, then every prime number $p_0 \ge 7$ is the sum of three primes: $3$ and the prime numbers $p_1, p_2$ such that $p_0-3 = p_1 + p_2$.

Comment: RyRy's proves lulu's comment: "If Goldbach is true, then every prime >5 is of this form. Just apply Goldbach to p−3". Is there a logic error in RyRy's proof to receive negative responses?